# How can i reload my layout and apply the changes in silverlight 4

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

i do a localized application using silverligth 4. 
after changing my culture thread i do

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
MainPage MyPage = new MainPage();
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(MyPage);
```

but i get an error **"value does not fall within the expected range"**
how can i reload the layout to apply the language changing

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am trying to reload one of the views into my Mainpage. I've seen all sorts of wild suggestions on how to do this.

My View is Project_ChangeRequest_Details.xaml which is the current view.

Taking almost exclusively from the initial msg of this thread, I wind up doing..

```
        LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
        Page MyPage = new Project_ChangeRequest_Details(); 
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(MyPage);
```

Works like a charm!

I'm using Silverlight 4 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(ContentProperty, new MainPage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:-

```
Application.Current.RootVisual = new MainPage();
```